# check if any property of an object with nested properties has any value - fail for dates

Tags: javascript, recursion

The following function returns true if any of the properties of an object have a value. This object could have nested objects

```
function hasValue(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = obj[key];
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                if (hasValue(value)) {
                    return true;
                }
            } else if (value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

For example for the following object returns true

```
const model = {
    criteria: '',
    category: '',
    range: {
        start: null,
        end: null
    },
    sample: '',
    another: {
        a: {
            b: {
                c: {
                    d: '',
                    e: {},
                    f: [1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is because the property `f` nested within `another` has the value of an array with a value

But this function fails with dates. For example. The following object should return true since the `a` and `end` properties have values. In this case dates

```
const model = {
    criteria: "",
    category: "",
    range: {
        start: { a: [new Date()] },
        end: new Date(),
    },
};
```

What is the reason for this behavior? and how could i solve it? Identify dates too

Answer (score 0):

The test of `typeof value === "object"` means that block that performs the recursive call will be entered for *any* non-primitive value, including Dates. Consider checking whether the value being iterated over is not only an object, but one whose internal prototype is `Object.prototype` or `Array.prototype`. If so, recurse; if not, return true.

```js
function hasValue(obj) {
    for (const key in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            const value = obj[key];
            if (typeof value === "object") {
                if ([Object.prototype, Array.prototype].includes(Object.getPrototypeOf(value))) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return hasValue(value);
                }
            } else if (value) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
const model = {
    criteria: "",
    category: "",
    range: {
        start: { a: [new Date()] },
        end: new Date(),
    },
};
console.log(hasValue(model));
```

Unless you *really need* the own property check, in most cases, you can simplify a bit with `Object.values`. (Since you don't care about the key except so that you can get to the value, easier to iterate over the values directly.)

```js
function hasValue(obj) {
  for (const value of Object.values(obj)) {
        if (typeof value === "object") {
            if ([Object.prototype, Array.prototype].includes(Object.getPrototypeOf(value))) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return hasValue(value);
            }
        } else if (value) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
const model = {
    criteria: "",
    category: "",
    range: {
        start: { a: [new Date()] },
        end: new Date(),
    },
};
console.log(hasValue(model));
```